# Converter cannot be applied to a property that expects the type IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, converters

I have a converter which implements `IValueConverter` but is not bindable to a property.

```
public class StatusToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Brushes.Red;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Within XAML I added the converter as resource and added Binding to the Element

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Converters:StatusToBrushConverter x:Key="StatusConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>            

<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter}, ElementName=userControl}"/>
```

But I constantly get the error

> An object of the type "StatusToBrushConverter" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter"

But the Converter implements the Interface `IValueConverter`. I tried several things:

- Rebuild, Clean, Build, Build Solution, etc.
- Completely new Converter --> Same

Previously written converters work. Thoughts?

Comment: What is "xx" in your question? That's somewhat important...

Comment: @canton7 probably `StatusToBrushConverter`

Comment: @Danis it might be, but that wouldn't make sense, as `StatusToBrushConverter` implements `IValueConverter`, as the question notes. If it's something else, that's the starting point for an investigation.

Comment: That message would typically appears if you forget to add `: IValueConverter` to your converter definition.

Comment: Also, make sure that your `IValueConverter` interface in the declaration of `StatusToBrushConverter` is actually `System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter`, and not another empty interface you've accidentally created (easily done, if you use `ctrl+.` to automatically add a `using` statement for an unknown type, and accidentally choose to create the new interface). Right-click the `IValueConverter` and "Go To Definition"

Comment: @canton7 Thanks for your suggestion. It is the right IValueConverter Interface. I checked that. But good point though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was following: The Converter was within a class library. Should not be a problem and was for other converters no problem. But I moved the Converter in  the WPF Project and now it worked. I did not change anything in the Converter.

The initial error with the error message was disappeared when I turned on my PC this morning. Several restarts of visual studio were not enough. Just the PC restart did the trick.

Thank you for your proposals. I tried all of them.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your `StatusToBrushConverter` class really implements the correct `IValueConverter` interface by using its fully qualified named:

```
public class StatusToBrushConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Brushes.Red;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You may also try to temporarily use the property element syntax for debugging purposes:

```
<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <Binding Path="Status" ElementName="userControl">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <local:StatusToBrushConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: (As noted in the comments, it can be very easy to accidentally create your own `IValueConverter` interface, instead of e.g. getting Intellisense to add `using System.Windows.Data;`. This is a great way to remove that possibility)

Answer (score 2):

Set your previously written working converters at your xaml file to see if problem persists, and isolate problem to xaml (or the converter you wrote).

Answer (score -1):

As an alternate to a converter one can create an associated Notified property on the VM to provide the color in question.

For example say your color actually keys off of another Notified Property called `IsValid`. When `IsValid` changes it should change the color on the rectangle.

```
 private bool _isValid;

 public bool IsValid
 {
     get { return _IsValid; }
     set 
     {
         _isValid = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("IsValid");
         NotifyPropertyChanged("UserStatusColor");
     }
 }


 public Brush UserStatusColor
 {
     get { return IsValid ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Red; }
 }
```

….

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding UserStatusColor}"/>
```

Hence the color changes without having to trojan horse a converter into the process.